# How to change colour of lightning ui:outputtext on any event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I am not able to change the colour of ui:outputText on any event(say doubleclick). Here is the code:

> Markup:

```
<ui:outputText aura:Id="outputTextId" dblclick="{!c.onTextDBClick}" />
```

> CSS:

```
.THIS.textClass{
color: #045489;
}
```

> Controller:

```
component.find("outputTextId").set("v.class", "textClass");
```

Comment: Are you able to debug and see if your component is assigned "textClass" upon dbl clicking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller

change

```
component.find("outputTextId").set("v.class", "textClass");
```

to

```
var outtext = cmp.find('outputTextId');
$A.util.addClass(outtext , 'textClass');
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm

component:

```
<aura:component >
    <ui:outputText aura:Id="outputTextId" value="test" dblclick="{!c.onTextDBClick}" />
</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
({
    onTextDBClick : function(cmp, event, helper) {
         var outtext = cmp.find('outputTextId');
        $A.util.addClass(outtext, 'textClass');
    }
})
```

style:

```
.THIS.textClass{
    color: blue;
}
```