# How to apply external styling to ui:outputText

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, html5, ui

I want to apply external style for truncating the text displayed by ui:outputText.

> Markup:

```
<lightning:layout multipleRows="false">
    <lightning:layoutItem class="slds-p-around--medium">
        <div>...</div>
        <div aura:id="divID" class="slds-show">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label">File Name</label>
            <br/>
            <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.docIconName}" size="small" class="slds-p-right--x-small " alternativeText="File Name"/>
            <ui:outputText aura:Id="outputTextId" value="{!v.selectedFile.name}" class="hideOverflow"/>
        <   lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" size="medium" value="{!index}" class="slds-button slds-button--icon slds-pill__remove" variant="bare" onclick="{! c.removeFile}" alternativeText="{!$Label.c.Close_LBL}" />
        </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

> style class:

```
.THIS .hideOverflow{
    max-width: 35em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

This styling is somehow not applied to ui:outputtext, probably because the UI rendered is in span tags and this external style is not applied on span. How can it be handled?

Please find actual and expected image:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried applying the style class in a div tag? `<div class="hideOverflow"><ui:outputText aura:Id="outputTextId" value="{!v.selectedFile.name}" /> </div>`

Comment: Add span to the selector then

Comment: @ArnoldJr. : Yes, but that makes the text to move to newline.

Comment: @Sarang Please take a look at this thread: [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148703/how-to-change-colour-of-lightning-uioutputtext-on-any-event/148704). Give it a try and see if the solution solves your issue.

Comment: Oh I just realized that the question was posted by yourself. :) This world is so small.